# Overlapping TextBlock and TextBox in Grid. TextBlock blocks manual data entry

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, user-controls

Behold the code below:

```
   <Grid>
        <TextBox>BOX</TextBox>
        <TextBlock>block</TextBlock>   
    </Grid>
```

The words block and BOX are written over eacht other and no keyboard input is possible in the textbox.

Now consider this:

```
<Grid>
   <TextBlock>block<TextBlock/>
   <TextBox>BOX<TextBox/>
</Grid>
```

The TextBox covers the TextBlock entirely and works as expected.

But say that I would like to be able to type in the textbox, while the content of the texblock remains visible (in a UserControl for instance). Is this possible?

Comment: Need more info. This works fine in a standalone project as you'd expect - the TextBox is on top of the TextBlock, so the TextBlock may as well not even be there.

Comment: @Kent: you are right. The issue is not related to a UserControl per se. I reworked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox>BOX</TextBox>
    <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False">block</TextBlock>   
</Grid>
```